# OSX SSD huge amount of writes

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd

I have a Mac retina Early 2015 model with 128gb SSD. According to a teardown from fixit, I have a MLC model, which is the worst in terms of SSD lifetime. I am a developer and actively use Android Studio and emulators and such to develop.

Currently, my system is running without shutdown since one week ago, and has 400 gb of data written and 300 gb of data read according to Activity Monitor. Kernel task is the worst culprit with 170gb and Android Studio has 4.59gb, but I imagine it is because of Android Studio that kernel task is writing so much.

I can't imagine my SSD lasting a long time when it has more than 50gb written everyday. Does anyone have the same "problem"? It is not a problem for now, but I would like to know if it is normal, or if there is something I can do to avoid so many writes.

Comment: I have averaged 32 GB per day on my SSD for over 3 years. I have 42 TB of writes already logged and the "wear level" is only 88% and total writes "99%" (whatever that means) according to DriveDx. I have absolutely no errors or bad sectors. This isn't going to be a problem.